# Как корректно подать SOURCE в PDO::prepare?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Осваиваю PDO, с конструкциями вида

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE ...");
```

или

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ...");
```

проблем не возникает. Делаю

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SOURCE /home/user/work/temp.sql");
```

ничего не происходит. Копирую эту строчку в mysql - все отрабатывает на ура. Подскажите в чем проблема.
И, да, c `$dbh->query()` - такая же история

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOURCE is definitely a command that is preprocessed by the mysql client.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315467/source-a-mysql-file-through-php).

То есть это не SQL запрос, а команда консольной утилиты. Поэтому выполнить ее через API невозможно.

Единственный вариант загрузить данные - это прочитать содержимое /home/user/work/temp.sql в переменную и всунуть её в `$dbh->exec()`

Comment: Благодарю, Ваши инструкции мне помогли.